# mysqli_stmt_bind_param for search

Tags: php, mysql, search, prepared-statement

Hi i need to change my already working query to a prepared statement. I just can't figure out how to get the `mysqli_stmt_bind_param();` right. my prepared statement is...

```
$query = "SELECT users.user_id, users.first_name WHERE users.active IS NULL AND";
foreach ($terms as $term) { // add the search term..
    $query .= " word=? OR"; // STUCK HERE
} 
$query = substr($query, 0, -3); // remove last OR.
    $query .= " GROUP BY users.user_id ORDER BY users.first_name DESC";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $term); // STUCK HERE
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user_id, $first_name);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);`
```

please any help would be great,
thanks.

Comment: What does `$terms` contain?

Comment: an array of names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest changing your `$query` building with this:

```
$query = "SELECT users.user_id, users.first_name WHERE users.active IS NULL AND (";
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $query .= "word=? OR ";
}
$query = rtrim($query, " OR "); // remove last OR .
$query .= ") GROUP BY users.user_id ORDER BY users.first_name DESC";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);
```

There are a few changes that I made here, such as replacing [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) with [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) (as it is shorter syntax, and is more dynamic), fixing the spacing, and putting all of your `word=?` and inside parentheses.

As for your actual parameter binding, I suggest changing it with this:

```
//use str_repeat to create a string of "s"'s equal to the amount of terms there are.
//use variable unpacking to unpack all of the terms into the function.
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, str_repeat("s", count($terms)), ...$terms);
```

Changes include using [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) which will generate a string of "s"'s the same length as the number of terms in `$terms`. I also use [variable unpacking](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) (Added in PHP version 5.6) to unpack all of the variables to be binded to the query.

---

**Note**: If you are using PHP version older than 5.6, I recommend you update, but also the variable unpacking will not work. Here is an alternative, simply replace your `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` with:

```
call_user_func_array("mysqli_stmt_bind_param", array_merge(array($stmt, str_repeat("s", count($terms)), $terms));
```

This utilizes [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to allow you to unpack the variables. The variable packing added in PHP version 5.6 is basically just sugar syntax for this older function.

Comment: hi the variable unpacking ...$terms is not working for me can i use something else ?

Comment: @sam67 What do you mean it's not working? What is it doing?

Comment: i get a syntax error as I'm not running the latest version of php. everything else is working i just need an alternative for ...$terms

Comment: @sam67 What version are you using? Variable unpacking is supported from 5.6.x and on, are you using a version older than 5.6? If so, I recommend upgrading. That version is almost 3.5 years old.

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.3 came with the server.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need to loop through your terms a second time, just simply pass a bunch of "word=? OR word=? OR word=?" etc. Using [`array_fill()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) you can simply accomplish that task.

The real problem comes into play when binding the params. You can use [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) to generate a string with 'ssssss'... equal to the number of terms to attach, and then use [Argument unpacking](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking) to attach the `$terms` array as parameters to `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`.

```
$query = "SELECT users.user_id, users.first_name WHERE users.active IS NULL AND ";
$query .= implode(
   ' OR ',
   array_fill(0, count($terms), 'word=?')
);

$query .= " GROUP BY users.user_id ORDER BY users.first_name DESC";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);
$types = str_repeat('s', count($terms));
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $types, ...$terms);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user_id, $first_name);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build an array and combine them on `OR`. Then call `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` with an array of parameters:

```
$query = "SELECT users.user_id, users.first_name WHERE users.active IS NULL AND";
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $or[] = " word=?";
}
$query .= implode("OR ", $or);
$query .= " GROUP BY users.user_id ORDER BY users.first_name DESC";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);
call_user_func_array("mysqli_stmt_bind_param",
                     array_merge(array($stmt, str_repeat("s", count($terms)), $terms));
```

I was going to edit this in as an alternate to the `foreach` but [FrankerZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4875631/frankerz) has it as part of their answer:

```
$query .= implode(" OR ", array_fill(0, count($terms), "word=?");
```